# Simplify Overridden equals and hashcode methods

Tags: java

I have a person class with overridden hashcode and equals, looks something like this :

```
class PersonKey {
  private String personUID;
  private String ssnUID;
  private String countryCode;

  
  public PersonKey (
      String personUID, String ssnUID, String countryCode) {
    this.personUID= personUID;
    this.ssnUID= countryCode;
    this.countryCode= countryCode;
  }
.....
}
```

This class already had `personUID` and `ssnUID` fields and I am introducing `countryCode` as a new field.
This class already had a complicated `hashcode` and `equals` method, with the inclusion of `countryCode` the logic got even more complicated. Is there a way I can reduce the Cyclomatic Complexity using inheritance or wrapper class?

HashCode :

```
@Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();

    result = prime * result;
    
    if (personUID != null) result += personUID.hashCode();
    else result += ((ssnUID == null) ? 0 : ssnUID.hashCode());

    if ((personUID != null || ssnUID != null)
        && (countryCode != null)) {
      result += countryCode.hashCode();
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Equals :

```
@Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    PersonKey other = (PersonKey) obj;
    if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType())) {
      return false;
    }

    // For the purposes of mapping any "empty" Person (null
    // personUID and ssnUID) is considered to be unique so return
    // false
    if ((ssnUID == null) && (personUID == null)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Only evaluate ssnUID if the personUID  is null
    if (personUID == null) {
      // If the current ssnUID matches the personUID 
      // from the other key the keys will be assumed to match
      if (ssnUID.equals(other.personUID)) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(countryCode) && StringUtils.isBlank(other.countryCode)) {
          return true;
        } else {
          if (countryCode.equals(other.contryCode)) return true;
        }
      } else if (other.personUID != null) {
        return false;
      }

      if (ssnUID.equals(other.ssnUID)) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(v) && StringUtils.isBlank(other.countryCode)) {
          return true;
        } else {
          if (countryCode.equals(other.countryCode)) return true;
        }
      }
    }

    // If the current personUID matches the personUID 
    // the keys will
    // be considered a match regardless of the value of the ssnUID.
    else if (personUID .equals(other.personUID)) {
      if (StringUtils.isBlank(contryCode) && StringUtils.isBlank(other.contryCode)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        if (countryCode.equals(other.countryCode)) return true;
      }
    }

    // If the current personUID matches the ssnUID
    // from the other key, and the other keys personUID is null
    // the keys will be considered a match
    else if ((other.personUID == null)
        && (personUID.equals(other.ssnUID))) {

      if (StringUtils.isBlank(contryCode) && StringUtils.isBlank(other.contryCode)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        if (countryCode.equals(other.countryCode)) return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: use of `Objects.hash()` and `Objects.equals()` should help

Comment: This kind of question is better asked at [codereview.se]

Comment: Posted in Code review here [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275114/simplify-overridden-equals-and-hashcode-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lombok's @EqualsAndHashCode would be the fastest option.

Example and documentation can be found here: https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode

If you create a new method in your class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
class PersonKey {
  private String personUID;
  private String ssnUID;
  private String countryCode;

  ...

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  public String uidOrSsn() {
     return personUID != null ? personUID : ssnUID;
  }

}
```

This way you're telling Lombok to only create the equals and hashCode for the `uidOrSsn()` method declared. Whichever the non-null value of personUID or ssnUID, then it will be generated.